# Install python dependencies not working

Tags: python, numpy

I recently formatted my hard drive and got rid of Windows and went to Linux.  I had a program that used to work fine before the reformat but isn't working fine now.

I believe it was written for 3.4 and not 2.7 since I used import tkinter and not import Tkinter.  In either case the program won't run now that I have made the switch over.  In 2.7 it does nothing...it acts like it has run through the code and then stops and gives me back the cursor when it should be popping up a t/Tkinter window displaying a graph.  In 3.4 I get the error saying numpy isn't installed.

When I apt-cache policy python-numpy it comes up showing it 1:1.8.2 is installed.  When I do the same for scipy it shows 0.13.3 is installed.  Seeing from other websites when I check for cython it shows 0.20.1+git90-gee6e38e is installed.  When I check for tk it comes up 8.6.0 is installed.

I'm a bit lost.  Why I do get the error code saying numpy isn't found when I got to run the program yet it is installed.  What do I have to do to get this program back up and running again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu then you have 2 versions of python executables - `python` and `python3`. So I think you need to install dependencies for python3 version by `sudo pip3 install numpy` or `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` if it exists in repos.

Comment: Got it, forget about having to have the difference between 2 and 3.  Haven't did any programming in about 1.5 years so not easy to forget simple little things like that.  Thanks much.

Comment: You're welcome. Please apply one of the answers as correct if it resolve your issue so it will help others too :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the librairies installed for Python 2... Did you use `pip` to install the librairies ?

Try :

```
pip3 install numpy
```

And same for your other librairies.